# How can we delete the created IAP?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, amazon-ec2, amazon-elastic-beanstalk

i just wanna to delete the created IAP from the amazon game. how can i delete the already created IA.

i just try to delete the IAP but there is no option here delete the created IAP, only new create IAP option here.